# htmlentities() does it remove return character and carriage return?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, textarea

I am creating a forum with PHP and MySQL with the help of PDO class. I have just started coding the forum and come up with a problem.

What I am doing is that

```
$post_body = htmlentities($_POST['post_body']);
```

get the user input like this and then send this to my function that then query this into the database like this

```
$str = $this->database->prepare('INSERT INTO `blah`,`blah_blah` VALUES(?,?)');
$str->bindValue(1,$someVal);
$str->bindvalue(2,$post_body);

$str->execute();
```

and when I display these details i do something like this

```
html_entity_decode($postDetails['post_body']); //$postDetails has been initialized correctly
```

Yes I have added try catches and handled the exceptions; but since this is a forum post, when a user presses return key, he/she expects to have a new line in the posted article. but when i display these posts i am losing every return/new lines in the post. Why and how do I get around this.

Explanation about wht this happens would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No! htmlentities() won't change line feeds in any way. Use [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) when you display the post to a user

Comment: What @MarkBaker writes is true. In other words: whitespaces are generally not rendered as expected in html. Things are different in textarea elements, but outside you either have to use a <pre> tag or convert relevant whitespaces.

Comment: Also note that encoding to store in the database and decoding when you get it back does nothing. If anything, it will use more cpu and space but it does not serve anything. You only need to encode when you output to html and if you use utf8 everywhere, you only need `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: I get it now @jeroen Will use only htmlspecialchars()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is not an html entity. It will not be decoded by that function.

Use `nl2br` to accomplish this like so:

```
echo nl2br(html_entity_decode($postDetails['post_body']))
```